# connecting to mysql and gae RDBMS with one application

Tags: mysql, eclipse, squirrel-sql

I have installed MySQL locally and I am trying to use it as a development server and then upload history and master data to the RDBMS on GAE. I can connect to the local MySQL with
... c:>mysql -u root -p   ...and I connect to the RDBMS with    ...c:>google_sql.cmd [instance] ...
but how do I do both connections in one program. I have tried using Squirrel and Eclipse and I can connect to local but not the GAE. What is the best method of attaching to both in one app.

Thanks  Dan

Comment: Have you read (and followed) [Google's instructions on how to get Squirrel working](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin_tools)?  Because I've already used Squirrel's DBCopy plugin to copy data between several brands of db's, and as far as I can see Google's db is - from the point of view of Squirrel - just another jdbc connection once properly setup.

Comment: make this an answer instead of comment because you did answer it. I thought it just needed the .exe but it needs the .jar, so search for google_sql.jar and use it as extra class path.   Thanks  Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read (and followed) [Google's instructions on how to get Squirrel working?](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin_tools) Because I've already used Squirrel's DBCopy plugin to copy data between several brands of db's, and as far as I can see Google's db is - from the point of view of Squirrel - just another jdbc connection once properly setup.